# Kafka Consumer reading messages only when two messages stack

Tags: java, kafka-consumer-api

We have a kafka producer that produces some messages once in a while.

I wrote a Consumer to consume these messages. Problem is, the messages are consumed only when 2 of them stack. For example if a message is produced at 13:00 the consumer doesn't do anything. If another message is produced at 13:01, the consumer consumes both messages. In kafkaTool, at consumer properties it's present a column called LAG that when the message is not consumed is 1.
Is there any config for this thing that I'm missing?

The Consumer Config:

```
16:43:04,472 INFO  [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig] (http--0.0.0.0-8180-1) ConsumerConfig values:
        request.timeout.ms = 180001
        check.crcs = true
        retry.backoff.ms = 100
        ssl.truststore.password = null
        ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
        receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
        ssl.cipher.suites = null
        ssl.key.password = null
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
        ssl.provider = null
        sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
        session.timeout.ms = 180000
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
        bootstrap.servers = [mtxbuctra22.prod.orange.intra:9092]
        client.id =
        fetch.max.wait.ms = 180000
        fetch.min.bytes = 1024
        key.deserializer = class io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
        sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
        auto.offset.reset = earliest
        value.deserializer = class io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
        ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
        partition.assignment.strategy = [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
        max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
        ssl.keystore.location = null
        ssl.truststore.location = null
        ssl.keystore.password = null
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
        security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
        auto.commit.interval.ms = 1000
        ssl.protocol = TLS
        sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
        connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
        ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
        group.id = ifd_006
        enable.auto.commit = true
        metric.reporters = []
        ssl.truststore.type = JKS
        send.buffer.bytes = 131072
        reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        ssl.keystore.type = JKS
        heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000

16:43:04,493 INFO  [io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig] (http--0.0.0.0-8180-1) KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig values:
        max.schemas.per.subject = 1000
        specific.avro.reader = true
        schema.registry.url = [http://mtxbuctra22.prod.orange.intra:8081]

16:43:04,498 INFO  [io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig] (http--0.0.0.0-8180-1) KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig values:
        max.schemas.per.subject = 1000
        specific.avro.reader = true
        schema.registry.url = [http://mtxbuctra22.prod.orange.intra:8081]
```

Kafka tool:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.
In documentation for kafka 0.9.0.1 it's stated that fetch.min.bytes is 1. But i have kafka 0.9.0.0. And the default value is 1024. So, only after 2 messages this value was passed. Changed the fetch.min.bytes to 1 and now it works ok.